# Sympy can't solve inequality with radicals

Tags: sympy, inequality

I need to solve this inequality:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozfni.png)

```
import sympy as sp
from sympy.abc import x,n

epsilon = 0.01
a = 2/3

xn = (n**3 + n**2)**(1/3) - (n**3 - n**2)**(1/3)
```

i tried to solve it like this:

```
ans = sp.solve_univariate_inequality(sp.Abs(xn-a) < epsilon,n,relational=False)
```

but received:

> NotImplementedError:  The inequality, Abs((x**3 -
> x**2)**0.333333333333333 - (x**3 + x**2)**0.333333333333333 + 2/3) <
> 0.01, cannot be solved using solve_univariate_inequality.

And tried so, but it didn't work

```
ans = sp.solve_poly_inequality(sp.Poly(xn-2/3-0.01, n, domain='ZZ'), '==')
```

but received:

> sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: (n**3 +
> n**2)**0.333333333333333 contains an element of the set of generators.

Same:

```
ans = sp.solveset(sp.Abs(xn-2/3) < 0.01, n)
```

> ConditionSet(n, Abs((n**3 - n**2)**0.333333333333333 - (n**3 +
> n**2)**0.333333333333333 + 0.666666666666667) < 0.01, Complexes)

How can this inequality be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x,n
a = S(2) / 3
epsilon = 0.01
xn = (n**3 + n**2)**(S(1)/3) - (n**3 - n**2)**(S(1)/3)
ineq = Abs(xn-a) < epsilon
```

Let's verify where `ineq` is satisfied with `plot_implicit`. Note that the left hand side of the inequality is valid only for `n>=1`.

```
plot_implicit(ineq, (n, 0, 5), adaptive=False)
```

[image]

So, the inequality is satisfied for values of `n` greater than `3.something`.

We can use a numerical approach to find the root of this equation: `Abs(xn-a) - epsilon`.

```py
from scipy.optimize import bisect
func = lambdify([n], Abs(xn-a) - epsilon)
bisect(func, 1, 5)
# out: 3.5833149415284424
```